# mysql code returns an empty set

Tags: mysql, database

I believe know where my problem is but I am unsure how to fix it. 
I am trying to find a trip where the the departure location is different from the Arrival location. But the way I wrote the code makes it so the it only returns sets that have the same departure and arrival location. How can I go about this issue? I want to find a trip that departs from Boston and arrives to Nassau while avoid using code like trip. DepartureLocCode = "BOS"

```
 SELECT name
    FROM staff, trip, locations
    WHERE trip.TripNum = staff.TripNum AND staff.DATE = trip.DATE AND trip.DATE = '2015-08-14' 
    AND (trip.ArrivalLocCode = locations.LocationCode AND locations.Location = "Nassau") 
    AND (trip.DepartureLocCode = locations.LocationCode And locations.Location = "Boston");
```

Answer (score 3):

First: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This is particularly true if you are learning SQL.

Your main problem, though, is that you need two joins:

```
SELECT name
FROM staff s JOIN
     trip t
     ON t.TripNum = s.TripNum JOIN
     locations la
     ON t.ArrivalLocCode = la.LocationCode JOIN
     locations ld
     ON t.DepartureLocCode = ld.LocationCode
WHERE t.DATE = '2015-08-14' AND
      la.Location = 'Nassau' AND 
      ld.Location = 'Boston';
```

Comment: This was very useful. I learned the importance of using JOIN thanks to you. Thank you very much. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the locations table twice like this. (I used modern explicit JOIN syntax)

```
SELECT name
FROM staff s
inner join trip t on t.TripNum = s.TripNum AND s.DATE = t.DATE
inner join locations l1 on t.ArrivalLocCode = l1.LocationCode
inner join locations l2 on t.DepartureLocCode = l2.LocationCode
WHERE t.DATE = '2015-08-14' 
AND l1.Location = 'Nassau' 
AND l2.Location = 'Boston';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to the location table twice.

I'm not a fan of implicit joins, it hampers readability IMHO, so I've made your joins explicit.

```
SELECT name
FROM staff s
JOIN trip t ON t.TripNum = staff.TripNum
JOIN locations l1 ON t.ArrivalLocCode = l1.locationCode
JOIN locations l2 ON t.DepartureLocCode = l2.locationCode
WHERE s.DATE = t.DATE
AND t.DATE = '2015-08-14'
AND l1.location = 'Nassau'
AND l2.location = 'Boston'
```